# Joining three tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables

```
File
- fileId(pk), code, & description
Hierarchy
 - fileId(fk), folderId(fk), folderKey(pk)
Folder
 - folderId(pk), folderName
```

In the Hierarchy table the fileId will be null for a folder and the folderId will be null for a file. 
I am trying to join all three to get what file is in which folder.

This query gives me no results

```
SELECT File.fileId, File.code, File.description, Hierarchy.folderId, 
       Hierarchy.folderKey, Folder.folderName
FROM  File INNER JOIN
      Hierarchy ON File.fileId = Hierarchy.fileId INNER JOIN
      Folder ON Hierarchy.folderId = Folder.folderId
```

Any clues?

Regards.

Comment: Are you sure there exists some related data among these tables?

Comment: The query looks legit, so the problem must be in your data.

Comment: also be careful with reserved words, file could be one

Comment: `In the Hierarchy table the fileId will be null for a folder and the folderId will be null for a file.`  So, where is the relationship stored then? It sounds like you don't have the required data actually stored anywhere. Your Heirarchy table should have an entry for every fileID that has both a fileID and the folderID that the file belongs to, but according to that statement that folderID is instead always null for file records.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT     File.fileId, File.code, File.description, Hierarchy.folderId, 
           Hierarchy.folderKey, Folder.folderName
FROM       File 
JOIN       Hierarchy ON File.fileId = Hierarchy.fileId
LEFT JOIN  Folder ON Hierarchy.folderId = Folder.folderId
```

Comment: it gives NULL for folder names infact it seems like the folder table is ignored

Comment: Do any of the `folderId`s in the `Hierarchy` table match those in the `Folder` table, where the `Hierarchy.fileId` column value exists in `File`? A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows in the left-hand table (`Hierarchy`) even if there are no matches in the right-hand table (`Folder`) - which appears to be the case if the `Folder` columns are all NULL in the result set. I think the queries you have tried on this page are correct in terms of what you're trying to achieve, however the data in the tables is not as you expect. Check your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select x.fileId, x.code, x.description, fd.folderId, x.folderKey, fd.folderName
From  Folder fd Left Join (
          select f.fileid, f.code, f.description, h.folderId, h.folderKey
          from [File] f join Hierarchy h 
                    on f.fileId = h.fileId ) x
         on fd.folderId = x.folderId
```

Comment: your making the query more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @mk_89, it is on the basis of every file should be in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your query if all there table have data corresponding to each other. If any two have and third may not have data for corresponding fields then your inner join will not yield any result. Left join your table in which there is possibility to not have data in it.