# Trouble with JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a bit of a trouble writing a query.

These are the two tables

Table 1 (no NULL values here):

```
FileInfo
 - fileId (pk)
 - fileCode
 - fileDescription
```

Table 2 (NULL values as explained below):

```
FileFolderHierarchy
 - fileId (fk)
 - folderId (fk)
 - fileFolderKey (pk)
```

Table 3 (no NULL values in here):

```
Folder
 - folderId (pk)
 - folderName
```

Table 2, FileFolderHierarchy, links Table 1 and Table 3

In FileFolderHierarchy a record will have either the folderId as NULL or the fileId as Null

Here are two records from FileFolderHierarchy:

```
fileId  folderId fileFolderKey
------------------------------
NULL    794     0001
3944    NULL    0001000000000000
```

The first record is a folder and the second is a file.

I want to get information about a file. Namely the fileId, fileCode, fileDescription, fileFolderKey, folderId, and folderName

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545735/joining-three-tables-in-sql) is a similar question that I asked yesterday.
Any query that I write seems to ignore either the fileId, or folderId or completely ignore the Folder table.

I haven't done much of SQL but reading about JOINS [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) tells me that a part of the query is resulting in NULL values which is why the folder info doesn't show up.

Any clues?

Regards.

Comment: How does a file relate to a folder? Through the fileFolderKey?

Comment: file relates to a folder through the FileFolderHierarchy table so yes the fileFolderKey

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: It's not a relationship if you have Nulls in all rows. Redesign the structure of `FileFolderHierarchy`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see that you will be facing is that the relation between file and folder is in 2 different rows in the FileFolderHierarchy table.

Retrieve the file info (or the folder info) on its own is simple

```
DECLARE @FileFolderHierarchy TABLE(
        fileId INT,
        folderId INT,
        fileFolderKey VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @FileFolderHierarchy SELECT NULL,794,'0001'
INSERT INTO @FileFolderHierarchy SELECT 3944,NULL,'0001000000000000'

DECLARE @FileInfo TABLE(
        fileID INT,
        fileCode VARCHAR(50),
        fileDescription VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @FileInfo SELECT 3944, 'TADA', 'TADA DESC'

DECLARE @Folder TABLE(
        folderId INT,
        folderName VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Folder SELECT 794, 'TADA FOLDER'

SELECT  fi.*
FROM    @FileFolderHierarchy ffh    INNER JOIN
        @FileInfo fi    ON  ffh.fileId = fi.fileID
```

as soon as you add the 3rd step, things go wonky

```
SELECT  fi.*
FROM    @FileFolderHierarchy ffh    INNER JOIN
        @FileInfo fi    ON  ffh.fileId = fi.fileID INNER JOIN
        @Folder f   ON  ffh.folderId = f.folderId
```

will return no results, as no such row exists.

At this point you might have thought about a parentID, which relates to the folder structure where the file belongs to a folder, and for that matter a folder can belong to a parent folder. You do not have such a structure, so we need to work with the Hierarchy key you provided.

So, looking at the data you provided, I would assume file with key 0001000000000000 relates to folder with key 0001. Here again I would have delimitted the fields for easy searching. So the file key should have read something like 0001\000000000000

Again, this does not seem to be the case, so lets look at what we can do.

You can try something like

```
SELECT  fi.*,
        f.*
FROM    @FileFolderHierarchy ffh    INNER JOIN
        @FileInfo fi    ON  ffh.fileId = fi.fileID INNER JOIN
        @FileFolderHierarchy ffhParent  ON  ffh.fileFolderKey LIKE  ffhParent.fileFolderKey + '%'
                                        AND ffh.fileFolderKey != ffhParent.fileFolderKey INNER JOIN
        @Folder f   ON  ffhParent.folderId = f.folderId
```

Unfortunately this will not return teh expexted results once you start looking at multi level hierarchies.

Answer (score -1):

Try a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT f.fileId, f.code, f.description, h.folderId, 
       h.folderKey, fl.folderName
FROM   File f
       FULL JOIN FileFolderHierarchy h
         ON f.fileId = h.fileId 
       FULL JOIN Folder fl
         ON h.folderId = fl.folderId
WHERE  fl.folderId is null
```